# darwin not able to stream uploaded 3gp files from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming, paperclip, darwin

I am trying to upload 3gp files into my rails application on ami instance using paperclip.
I then move that 3gp file to darwing streaming server folder to stream it.
To have a better identification of file names , it has been prepended with some ids'.

Now when i am trying to play that video through its rtsp link on mobile, i am not able to play that video. Interestingly, when i download that video to my local machine and play it with say vlc - i am able to do that.

what could be missing here.

Answer (score 0):

To stream a 3gp or mp4 file via darwin streaming server, you must ensure that the media file is hinted.
To add hint track to a 3gp or mp4 file, you can use MP4Box

```
http://gpac.wp.institut-telecom.fr/mp4box/

mp4box -hint sample.3gp
```